# Inconsistent time series given equal spacing in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm plotting a stacked line chart from a pandas dataframe. The data was collected irregularly over the course of two days. In the image below, you can see that the time change between equal intervals varies (~7 hours to ~36 hours between equally spaced intervals). I don't want this to happen, I want points on the graph to be stretched and squeezed appropriately such that time scales linearly with the x-axis. How can I do this?

The data was read in as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv("filepath", index_col=0)
df = df.T
```

Above, I had to transpose the dataframe for the pandas stacked line plot to work as I wanted it to. The plot was produced as follows:

```
plot = df.plot.area(rot=90)
plot.axhline(y=2450, color="black")
```

[image]

In response to ImportanceOfBeingErnest, here is a minimal, complete, and verifiable example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl

dateTimeIndex = ["04.12.17 23:03", "05.12.17 00:09", "05.12.17 21:44", "05.12.17 22:34", "08.12.17 16:23"]

d = {'one' : pd.Series(abs(np.random.randn(5)), index=dateTimeIndex),
     'two' : pd.Series(abs(np.random.randn(5)), index=dateTimeIndex),
     'three' : pd.Series(abs(np.random.randn(5)), index=dateTimeIndex)}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

plot = df.plot.area(rot=90)
```

Here is what the dataframe looks like (random values will vary):

```
                one       three     two
04.12.17 23:03  0.472832  0.283329  0.739657
05.12.17 00:09  3.166099  1.065015  0.561079
05.12.17 21:44  0.209190  0.674236  0.143453
05.12.17 22:34  1.275056  0.764328  0.650507
08.12.17 16:23  0.764038  0.265599  0.342435
```

and the plot produced:

[image: Minimal, verifiable example]

As you can tell, the dateTimeIndex entries are rather random but they are given equal spacing on the x-axis. I don't mind if the tick marks coincide with the data points. I only want time to scale linearly. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Have you tried resampling (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) the data, e.g. to minutes and fill (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) missing values with `ffill`?

Comment: As mentioned above you have to select style of filling to make a series with linear time. You have to fill missing values with Nan, interpolation data or  constant.

Comment: There might be several issue here. Please provide a [mcve], otherwise one cannot find out.

Comment: jo9k, I don't understand how the resampling works? Not sure it would work very effectively for my data as the timestamps are relatively random (and include detail down to the second) Is there a way to avoid this? Also seems like a lot of unnecessary data is being created.

Comment: ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I've added a more comprehensive example that you can use yourself. I hope this makes what I'm experiencing/trying to achieve clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whats happening above is pandas is just using the strings as the x-ticks.  You need to make the `dateTimeIndex` a datetime object:

```
dateTimeIndex = pd.to_datetime( ["04.12.17 23:03", "05.12.17 00:09", 
                "05.12.17 21:44", "05.12.17 22:34", "08.12.17 16:23"])

d = {'one' : pd.Series(abs(np.random.randn(5)), index=dateTimeIndex),
     'two' : pd.Series(abs(np.random.randn(5)), index=dateTimeIndex),
     'three' : pd.Series(abs(np.random.randn(5)), index=dateTimeIndex)}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)    
plot = df.plot.area(rot=90)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much!